# ggplot2: how to combine 2 plots into one when one plot has error bars and one does not

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot two data frames next to each other using `facet_wrap` in `ggplot2`. However one of the plots has error bars and the other does not. I am able to plot the one with error bars fine, and I can plot the two data frames next to each other if I don't include the error bars. I have been unable to plot the two next to each other with error bars on the one graph.

A subset of my data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(farm = c("F1", "F1", 
"F1", "F1"), index = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("HT", "Mid-T", "Outside Mid-T", "Outside South"
), class = "factor"), sensorheight = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yrmonth = structure(c(1491004800, 
1496275200, 1491004800, 1496275200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), monthindex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Spring", 
"Winter"), class = "factor"), N = c(2, 2, 1, 1), TempC = c(2.06446759259259, 
6.68402777777778, 1.32268518518518, 5.63194444444445), sd = c(1.17081824208967, 
0.034373246307681, NA, NA), se = c(0.827893518518518, 0.0243055555555567, 
NA, NA), ci = c(10.5193845460483, 0.308831365115372, NA, NA)), .Names = c("farm", 
"index", "sensorheight", "yrmonth", "monthindex", "N", "TempC", 
"sd", "se", "ci"), row.names = c(7L, 9L, 20L, 22L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(farm = c("F2", "F2", "F2", 
"F2", "F2", "F2"), location = c("Outside", 
"Outside", "Outside", "Permanent", "Permanent", "Permanent"), 
    sensorheight = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yrmonth = structure(c(1459468800, 
    1462060800, 1464739200, 1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), TempC = c(3.43055555555556, 
    5.34520609318996, 10.6064814814815, 3.21701388888889, 5.30264336917563, 
    9.8587962962963)), .Names = c("farm", "location", "sensorheight", 
"yrmonth", "TempC"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's what I can plot:

```
ggplot(df1, 
       aes(x=yrmonth,y=TempC, colour=index)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=TempC-sd, ymax=TempC+sd), size = .5) 

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x=yrmonth,y=TempC)) +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x=yrmonth,y=TempC)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ farm, scales = "free_x")
```

When I try to plot them together:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x=yrmonth,y=TempC)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=TempC-sd, ymax=TempC+sd), size = .5)  +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x=yrmonth,y=TempC)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ farm, scales = "free_x")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in if (empty(data)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do any data manipulation, you just need to change around your `ggplot` call a little. This should work:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=yrmonth)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=TempC)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=TempC-sd, ymax=TempC+sd), size = .5)  +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x=yrmonth,y=TempC)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ farm, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

A few notes on what I changed: I added `df1` to the `ggplot()` call so that `facet_wrap` knows where to get the `farm` object from. I also added the `aes(x=yrmonth)` in the `ggplot()` call so that `geom_errorbar` can inherit it. This saves some extra typing.

Comment: Thanks! works great. One follow up I want to add `colour=index, group=index` so that it colors each line by the index. I tried adding it to `aes()` in `ggplot` or the two `geom_lines` but it didn't work.

Comment: @phaser, I think you need to specify those in your first `geom_line` b/c the 2nd `geom_line` doesn't have and `index` column

Answer (score 1):

A different approach, you can do this if you merge the two data.frames (`df1`, `df2`) together.

```
library(tidyverse)
#Merge the two data.frames together
df1 %>% dplyr::full_join(., df2) %>% 
  #plot
  ggplot(., aes(yrmonth, TempC))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=TempC-sd, ymax=TempC+sd), size = .5)+
  facet_wrap( ~ farm, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]